# Python packages depending on libxml2 and libxslt

Tags: python, dependencies, lxml, libxml2, libxslt

Apart from `lxml`, is anyone aware of Python packages that depend on libxml2 and libxslt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See e.g. the list [here](http://www.xmlsoft.org/XSLT/python.html) -- not exhaustive, as the page itself says, but a start.